# Merging data based on ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored proc in which I am trying to setup the initial pull into a table.

based on the parameters @being_date and @end_date, the stored proc pulls the data and aggregates it for about 20 clients.

However, the 21st client has a unique situation.

Data after 201501 should be pulled from a specific table for specific geo. regions.
Data prior to 201501 should be pulled from all_employees table.

Because of this requirement, I cannot execute the proc for a full range 201401 thru 201803. I have to run it month-month.

```
create procedure sp_agg_emp_data (@begin_month int, @end_month int, @clientid varchar(30)) 
as
begin
declare @cutoff_month int 

IF @clientid = 'NNA' 
BEGIN
 select @cutoff_month = min(monthofs) from all_na_employees

 IF @begin_month < @cutoff_month
 begin
    select *
    into _agg_emp
    from all_employees
 end
 else
 begin
   select *
   into _agg_temp
   from (
     select *
     from all_employees where geo_region <> 'NA'
      union all
     select *
     from all_na_employees where geo_region = 'NA'
     ) x
 end
end
 ELSE
 BEGIN
     select *
    into _agg_emp
    from all_employees
  END
end
```

The execution hangs at this:
 select @cutoff_month = min(monthofs) from all_employees

the query plan is not showing anything abnormal.

is there a more simpler and elegant way of doing this?

Update --  adding details

1. Yes the 21st client is constant. This step is the first step - the
   process gets the data into the table and then aggregates at various
   levels using dynamic sql.
2. The volume of data is not high at all - around 100K rows. Normally,
   it takes 1.5 mins to execute. But for this client, it is just stuck
   at that step.

I turned on the execution plan in SSMS and printed debug statements. The run doesnt go beyond that step.

Comment: Is the 21st client constant, like are you aware of the name/number for that client so that could be calculated separately?

Comment: How many records in `all_employees`? Are there any indexes? How long does this statement take by itself? What makes you think it's hanging on this line?

Comment: thanks for responding. edited the question and added detail there.

Comment: how do you differentiate the `21st` client from the rest ? I don't see any Client ID or anything that identify the client in your query

Comment: thanks for responding @Squirrel  - this is a small subset of a much larger query to illustrate the problem. ClientID is a parameter to the stored proc in the actual procedure. I will update the question to show it there.

Answer (score 0):

One reason would be that there is no index on column `monthofs`. Maybe `all_na_employees` has many rows or it is a view or `monthofs` is computed. Try to add an index to sort it `DESC`.

Comment: oddly enough, the index exists albeit without the sort desc. would that make a difference?

Comment: You said that the execution hangs at this query. Are you sure that this one is not completed? Maybe this is the last one completed. Anyway, did you tried to execute just this query, by itself, outside the procedure? Does it hangs?